# Send SMS in python from android phone. (Python)

Tags: python

I want to run a script in python that sends a text message to a selected number from my android phone. Is this even possible with python?

Answer (score 1):

Since the script has to send a message from your Android phone, I assume you want to run the script on your phone as well. This [blog post](http://google-opensource.blogspot.nl/2009/06/introducing-android-scripting.html) suggests that it is (or was) possible, using the Android Scripting Environment.